# Parallelize map() operation on single Observable and receive results out of order

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, reactive-programming, rx-java2

Given an `Observable<Input>` and a mapping function `Function<Input, Output>` that is expensive but takes variable time, is there a way to call the mapping function in parallel on multiple inputs, and receive the outputs in the order they're produced?

I've tried using `observeOn()` with a multi-threaded `Scheduler`:

```java
PublishSubject<Input> inputs = PublishSubject.create();
Function<Input, Output> mf = ...
Observer<Output> myObserver = ...

// Note: same results with newFixedThreadPool(2)
Executor exec = Executors.newWorkStealingThreadPool();

// Use ConnectableObservable to make sure mf is called only once
// no matter how many downstream observers
ConnectableObservable<Output> outputs = inputs
    .observeOn(SchedulersFrom(exec))
    .map(mf)
    .publish();
outputs.subscribe(myObserver1);
outputs.subscribe(myObserver2);
outputs.connect();

inputs.onNext(slowInput); // `mf.apply()` takes a long time to complete on this input
inputs.onNext(fastInput); // `mf.apply()` takes a short time to complete on this input
```

but in testing, `mf.apply(fastInput)` is never called till after `mf.apply(slowInput)` completes.

If I play some tricks in my test with `CountDownLatch` to ensure `mf.apply(slowInput)` can't complete until after `mf.apply(fastInput)`, the program deadlocks.

Is there some simple operator I should be using here, or is getting `Observables` out of order just against the grain of RxJava, and I should be using a different technology?

---

**ETA:** I looked at using `ParallelFlowable` (converting it back to a plain `Flowable` with `.sequential()` before subscribing `myObserver1/2`, or rather `mySubscriber1/2`), but then I get extra `mf.apply()` calls, one per input per `Subscriber`. There's `ConnectableFlowable`, but I'm not having much luck figuring out how to mix it with `.parallel()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `observeOn` operator does not support concurrent execution for alone. So, how about using flatMap? Assume the `mf` function needs a lot time.

```java
    ConnectableObservable<Output> outputs = inputs
        .flatMap(it -> Observable.just(it)
            .observeOn(SchedulersFrom(exec))
            .map(mf))
        .publish();
```

or

```java
    ConnectableObservable<Output> outputs = inputs
        .flatMap(it -> Observable.just(it)
            .map(mf))
            .subscribeOn(SchedulersFrom(exec))
        .publish();
```

**Edit 2019-12-30**

If you want to run tasks concurrently, but supposed to keep the order, use `concatMapEager` operator instead of `flatMap`.

```java
    ConnectableObservable<Output> outputs = inputs
        .concatMapEager(it -> Observable.just(it) // here
            .observeOn(SchedulersFrom(exec))
            .map(mf))
        .publish();
```

Comment: How does this maintain the original order?

Comment: I guess you want to keep the original order even the tasks are running concurrently. Then how about using `concatMapEager` instead of `flatMap`?

Comment: Yes. concatMapEager should work. I wasn't aware of this operator. Can you please edit your answer, as currently it does not answer the question.

Comment: See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59417940/parallelize-map-operation-on-single-observable-and-receive-results-out-of-orde#comment105398885_59484321) on @PrashantPandey's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't sound possible to me, unless Rx has some very specialised operator to do so. If you're using `flatMap` to do the mapping, then the elements will arrive out-of-order. Or you could use `concatMap` but then you'll lose the parallel mapping that you want.

Edit: As mentioned by another poster, concatMapEager should work for this. Parallel subscription and in-order results.

Comment: Note that I didn't say I wanted to receive the outputs in the order I _subscribed_, but rather than in the order they're _produced_. So based on [this FAQ](https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2017/08/flatmap-vs-concatmap-vs-concatmapeager.html) I think `flatMap()` is correct for the behavior I want.

Comment: Absolutely, that will work. flatMap doesn't care when the outputs are produced.